# Verifying Pullback Identity for Symplectomorphism

Tags: manifolds, differential-forms, symplectic-geometry

I'm having trouble verifying an identity in symplectic geometry.  Consider the cotangent bundle $T^*M$ over a smooth manifold $M$ where we can express coordinates locally as $(x,\xi)$.  Let $\omega$ be the canonical symplectic form on this space where we can express $\omega = -d\alpha$ for the canonical 1-form, and
$$
\omega \;\; =\;\; \sum_i dx^i\wedge d\xi^i \hspace{2pc}\text{and} \hspace{2pc} \alpha = \sum_i \xi_i dx^i = \left (d\pi_p\right )^*\xi
$$

where $p =(x,\xi)$ and $d\pi_p:T_p\left (T^*M\right ) \to T_xM$

> For any $h\in C^\infty(M)$ let $\tau_h:T^*M \to T^*M$ be the map given
>   in local coordinates by  $$ \tau_h(x,\xi) \;\; =\;\; (x, \xi + dh_x).
>  $$ The goal is to prove the identity $$\tau_h^*\alpha \;\; =\;\; \alpha +
>  \pi^*dh$$ where $\pi:T^*M \to M$ is the canonical projection.  Once this is done, it is quite simple to show that $\tau_h^*\omega = \omega$, proving it to be a symplectomorphism.

I'm having a great deal of difficulty proving this claim.  I've tried expressing the claim in terms of tangent vectors in $T_p(T^*M)$ but this got rather messy.  I suspect there is a slick way to do this that I'm just missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach is to prove the identity in Darboux coordinates $(x, \xi)$. Write $(x', \xi') = \tau_h(x, \xi) = (x, \xi + dh_x)$, hence $(x')^i = x^i$ and $\xi'_i = \xi_i + \frac{\partial h}{\partial x^i}(x)$. It follows that
$$ \tau_h^*\alpha = \tau_h^*\left( \sum_i \xi_i dx^i \right) = \sum_i \xi'_i d(x')^i = \sum_i\left(\xi_i + \frac{\partial h}{\partial x^i}(x)\right) dx^i = \alpha + dh_x . $$

Comment: I want to just double-check one thing.  You claim that $\xi_i' = \xi_i  +\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}$.  Can we understand this in the sense that if $f$ is a smooth function and $\eta$ is a form, then we in general have $\tau^*(f\eta) = (f\circ \tau)\tau^*\eta$?

Comment: @Mnifldz What you describe rather explains my second equality. To explain my claim, we need to understand the meaning of $\tau_h(x, \xi) = (x, \xi + dh)$. I'd say that the rhs is expressed in *fixed cotangent chart* $(X, \Xi)$; an initial pair $(X_i = x, \Xi_i = \xi)$ is sent by $\tau_h$  to a final pair $(X_f = x', \Xi_f = \xi')$; the specific expression of $\tau_h$ yields $x' = x$ and $\xi' = \xi + dh$. This last equality is the equality of the coordinates of the $n$-tuple $\Xi$, hence $\xi'_i = \xi_i + \partial h/\partial X^i(x)$. A usual abuse of notation is to write $x$ instead of $X$.